# Is the following estimate of this integral correct?

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, holder-inequality

Let $\epsilon>0$ and suppose that $U_t^\epsilon, V_t^\epsilon, \Gamma^{2\epsilon}_t$ are some real functions of time (depending on $\epsilon$) defined on $[0,T]$, $T < \infty$ and assume that for  $p >1$
$$|U_t^\epsilon|^p \leq C (1+\int_0^t |V_r^\epsilon|^p   dr)$$
for every $t \in [0,T]$, for some $C>0$ independent of $\epsilon$ and that $\Gamma^{2\epsilon}_t \leq C$ for some $C>0$ independent of $\epsilon$.
Assume moreover that $G(x,y)$ is a sublinear function.
Now define
\begin{align*}|V_t^\epsilon| & = \int_0^t \frac{1}{\epsilon} e^{-\frac{2 \delta}{\epsilon} (t-s)} |G(U_s^\epsilon, \Gamma^{2\epsilon}_s)|  ds \\
& =  \int_0^{t/\epsilon} e^{-2 \delta (t / \epsilon - s)} |G(U_{\epsilon s}^\epsilon, \Gamma^{2\epsilon}_{\epsilon s})|  ds 
\end{align*}
Is then the following calculation that I've done correct?
By Holder's inequality, some changes of variables and the sublinearity of $G$ have:
\begin{align*}
|V_t^\epsilon|^p 
&  \leq   \left( \int_0^{t / \epsilon}  e^{-\frac{ \delta p}{ (p-1)} (t / \epsilon - s)} ds \right)^{p-1}  \int_0^{t / \epsilon}  e^{-\delta p (t / \epsilon - s)} |G(U_{\epsilon s}^\epsilon, \Gamma^{2\epsilon}_{\epsilon s})| ^p  ds\\
&\leq   \left( \int_0^{t / \epsilon }   e^{-\frac{ \delta p}{ (p-1)} \sigma} d\sigma \right)^{p-1}  \int_0^{t } \frac{1}{\epsilon}  e^{-\delta p (t  - s)/ \epsilon} (1+|U_s^\epsilon|^P+ |\Gamma^{2\epsilon}_s|^p ) ds \\
& \leq C+ C  \int_0^{t }  \frac{1}{\epsilon}  e^{-\delta p (t  - s)/ \epsilon}\int_0^s |V_r^\epsilon|^p   drds  \\
& =C + C  \int_0^{t } \left( \int_0^{(t-r)/ \epsilon}   e^{-\delta p \sigma} d\sigma \right)  |V_r^\epsilon|^p  dr \\
& \leq  C + C  \int_0^{t }  |V_r^\epsilon|^p  dr 
\end{align*}
for some $C>0$ independent of $\epsilon$.